# I'm looking for a Responsive Web charting tool

Tags: ajax, html, charts, responsive-design

I'm looking for a way to display charts using HTML5 and fully reponsive to screen resolution. If you have something else not using Flash, I'm open to suggestion.

Also, I would like to be able to create these kind of charts:

- Pie charts
- Horizontal / vertical lines charts
- Countries charts (if possible)

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) produces pie charts and line charts without using Flash. Resizes great with any screen resolution. Lots of configurable options with its API. Easy to feed it data.

I've used Highcharts to create line charts based on existing data from HTML5 Web SQL databases, works great.

Comment: I've checked out [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) and the new [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) and have in both cases been unable to make a chart fluid/responsive, so I'll try out Highcharts. (Flot)[http://code.google.com/p/flot/] now seems to have a resize ability as well : http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/resize.html